# How to hide new content type from create content menu

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I am a newbie in drupal, i have created a new content type 'new', I have two type of roles Editor and manager. Editor must be able to add content in to the new content type but manager wont. I have specified in the module code that

```
function new_access($op, $node, $account) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'create':
    return user_access('create NEW', $account);
  }
}
```

Now the editor got the permission for this and he can add content, but when manage login when also view the new content type but clciking on the menu will show 'Access Denied'

I want to make this content type in such a way that, when manage logins the content type 'New' must not be in the create content link

please help

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use the Drupal permission system? You can define the access to the creation/edit/delete/... of all content types on a per-role basis.

Comment: Drupal core code already defines the permissions for existing content type, including the ones implemented from third-party modules; in particular, it defines the following permissions: "create CONTENT_TYPE", "edit CONTENT_TYPE", "delete CONTENT_TYPE", "edit own CONTENT_TYPE", "delete own CONTENT_TYPE". `CONTENT_TYPE` is the identifier of the content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've created the new content type through the Drupal interface and not through a custom module (that is, you went to *Content management* -> *Content types* and added it there), it's much easier to restrict this.

Simply go to *User management* -> *Permissions*, look under the *node* heading, and uncheck *Create NEW content* under the *Editor* role.

If you have created the content type through the use of a custom module, you'd still go to the *Permissions* page, but in your custom module, you need to implement [`hook_perm()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_perm) in addition to `hook_access()`:

```
function new_perm() {
  return array('create NEW');
}
```

Then you can use `user_access('create NEW', $account);` to check against the `create NEW` permission.

Comment: I done this, but the link of the new content type is there and when I click on it says Access Denied, I dont want this link here ,Thank you

Comment: Did you rebuild the menu after making the changes?